# Designer Popup Editor Issue

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, reporting, telerik, telerik-reporting

In a custom toolset I have installed for Visual Studio, there is a popup window that should appear to me so that I can manipulate one of the lists (an in-built editor).  The component is Telerik, but I don't think that has anything to do with it (maybe).

The popup window is no longer popping up to me.  I wonder if it got minimized or it's a z-index thing, where the window is behind VS?  But this locks up VS, and I can't do anything within it until I cancel the window.  But I can't cancel the window because I can't see it... and so that is really slowing me down and is really frustrating.

Is there a way to get around this?  A key press to bring this to the front or give it the focus?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to cancel it with ESC. You can also test if you can find the window with CTRL-TAB. If this not help then an uninstall, boot and reinstall seems the only possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a z-index issue indeed. Try using FireBug or IE dev toolbar to get a hold on the popup and its container and check their styles and z-indices.

Dick

Comment: Sorry, not a web component, a component within Visual Studio itself... It's a VS issue.